# Empty string as default value for enum type column instead of nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, activerecord, enums

The problem is that I'm receiving empty string instead of *nil* as default value for *enum* column in PostgreSQL database, while creating new *ActiveRecord* object. Here is some more information.

My migration:

```
class CreateTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TYPE ticket_status AS ENUM ('submitted', 'open', 'closed');
    SQL

    create_table :tickets do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.column :status, :ticket_status

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {
    submitted:  'submitted',
    open:       'open',
    closed:     'closed'
  }

  validates :status, inclusion: { in: Ticket::STATUS.values }, allow_nil: true
end
```

My goal is to allow *nil* value in database table, but when I'm trying to create new object, I'm receiving "not included in the list error":

```
2.2.0 :005 >   Ticket.create!
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Status is not included in the list
```

This happens because new object is created with empty string as default value in status column, while other columns get correct nil values:

```
2.2.0 :010 >   Ticket.new
 => #<Ticket id: nil, name: nil, status: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

One more condition here, that I do want to use native PostgreSQL ENUM type, instead of integer mapping.

Comment: Try setting a default value with `t.column :status, :ticket_status, default: nil`

Answer (score 1):

There is an `allow_blank` option.

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: Ticket::STATUS.values }, allow_blank: true
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

**Update**: For this to work, you should add empty string to the enum:

```
CREATE TYPE ticket_status AS ENUM ('', 'submitted', 'open', 'closed');
```

Comment: But an empty string is not a valid value for a column of type `ticket_status` so the validation will pass but the database will raise an exception. Changing the validation options is just moving the error around in this case.

Comment: Yes you are right, but empty string can be added to the database enum. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! `allow_blank` option did the trick, but there is even more magic somewhere inside `ActiveRecord` class. I just changed validation rule as you suggested  and Voila! Object still contains "" as value, but it's saved as `NULL` in database. It still looks like a bit strange to me, but at least I don't have superfluous value in ENUM definition.